# Friendly line editing with `PYTHONINSPECT`

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple script that does a little environment setup and then drops a user into an interactive console (at least in some cases).  To drop the user into the interactive console, I'm setting the `PYTHONINSPECT` environment variable as [documented](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONINSPECT).

> This variable can also be modified by Python code using `os.environ` to force inspect mode on program termination.

Unfortunately, once I'm dropped into the interactive console, line editing seems to be sub-par (e.g. `Ctrl + a` no longer moves the caret to the beginning of the line).

Here's an almost trivial script that you can play around with:

```
# test.py
import os
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = '1'
```

Note that running `python test.py` will drop you into an interactive session, but typical line editing features are gone.  If you run `python -i test.py`, the typical line editing features work just fine.

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I am on OS-X, using python 2.7.10:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 18:05:06) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The problem seems to be gone in my python3.5 build.

Is there anything I can do to get those nice line editing features back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it looks like the simple answer is to just import readline:

```
import os
import readline
os.environ['PYTHONINSPECT'] = '1'
```

Comment: Probably should have tried this _before_ posting the question, but then I guess the answer wouldn't be available for the rest of the world to see...